# Why won't iOS launch a PWA after changes in its manifest.json?

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps

I made a PWA so my web app can be used offline. This works on iOS. However, after I make a change to its `manifest.json` (on the server), the add-to-home-screen web app will only show its splash screen image and then hang on a white screen.

This even happens after changes as small as changing the version number (which supposedly makes iOS to check for updated files on the server). I tested on iOS 12.1.4 and the iOS 12.1 simulator.

How can I prevent that from happening?

Here's my manifest.json, with the list of icons removed for brevity:

```js
{
  "name": "My App Name",
  "short_name": "App Name",
  "version": "2.2.2",
  "theme_color": "#ffcc00",
  "background_color": "#382d00",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "landscape",
  "scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/",
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

*Update:* Even normal iOS Safari just shows a blank screen when I go to the URL, until I remove the website from its history.

Comment: It says from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/#test), if you update your manifest.json file in the future, those changes won't be automatically picked up by the users unless they re-add your app to their home screen. This is an expected behavior.

Comment: Interesting! Somehow I can't find that on that page. Anyway my main issue is that the web app won't show anything but the splash screen and a white screen after a change to the manifest. So apparently iOS does check for updates and for some reason decides not to continue loading the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm facing the same situation, currently I'm solving it by adding a check after 5 seconds, if the pwa hasn't yet loaded , I trigger a reload which fixes the issue.

But this is far from ideal, so I'll keep searching for a better solution